# Memory consumption of very long UIScrollView in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

My UIScrollView is very very long in width, and it contains thousands of UIImageView objects.

Does the above UIScrollView and UIImageView objects consume a lot of memory ?

When an UIImageView object is scrolled away from the visible area, will it be auto released to free the memory ?

Any good approach to manage the memory in the above scenario ?

Thanks.

Comment: No it wont be autoreleased, you have to handle it yourself. what you can do just fill imageView.image = nil, this will remove the image and when you again come on the same screen area you will need to load it again.

Comment: Thanks, Ravin. How to check the UIImageView objects are out of the visible area ? Can an UIImageView observe itself for moving away from the screen ?

Comment: Any reason why this can't be a UITableView?

Comment: Thank you. I also think that UITableView is an alternate solution. Does UITableView automatically free the cells (which containing UITableView objects) when they are not visible ??

Comment: as you said your scrollview is has very long width , I think TableView would be different solution for this. Yes you can do it using scrollView's scoll delegate methods. you will use offset to know the scrolled portion and using it you can calculate the visible area.

Answer (score 4):

1. For the first question Yes, they will consume al lot of memory.
2. For the second question No they will not be released.
   When you add an view to your scroll view "addSubView" it will send an retain to that object. So you also need to remove that view from the superView in your case your scroll view. You can tag all your image view and when is out of screen you can remove it from super view to keep memory usage  low.

This is best explained in WWDC 2010 Session Videos in Session 104 - Designing Apps with Scroll Views. You find this for free in iTunes U

Comment: I have scrollview with paging enabled, and I'm adding custom UIView say **'customView'** (that contains few buttons and web views) on it. When scrollview is scrolled, previously added customView is getting removed and same customView with different values is added again. But memory keep increasing when i scroll back-and-forth. My code is long enough, so couldn't post it. What could be the possible cause for this ?

Comment: Check for retain circles references. The best way to debug is to add -(void)dealloc method in your views and log the exact time when that view is released.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I've identified issue and its UIWebView which is not getting released even after setting it to nil. I've searched for webview release issue, but no solution has worked.